# Laravel 4 Migrations throwing 1072 error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a couple of migrations in a new Laravel 4 project. One is for regions and the other for areas. Each region has a number of areas, and areas belong to regions.

I have used Laravel 4 and the migration functions on a number of occasions but have never come accross this issue before. When I run `php artisan migrate:install` followed by `php artisan migrate` I get the following error:

```
$ php artisan migrate
  [Exception]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'region_
  id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `areas` add constraint areas_r
  egion_id_foreign foreign key (`region_id`) references `regions` (`id`)) (Bi
  ndings: array (
  ))
migrate [--bench[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--path[="..."]] [--package[="...
"]] [--pretend] [--seed]
```

// The regions migration

```
class CreateRegionsTable extends Migration {

 /**
  * Run the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function up()
  {
    // Creates the regions table
   Schema::create('regions', function($table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 160)->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
  }
}
```

// The areas migration

```
class CreateAreasTable extends Migration {

 /**
  * Run the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function up()
  {
    // Creates the cemeteries table
    Schema::create('areas', function($table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->foreign('region_id')->references('id')->on('regions');
        $table->string('name', 160)->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You have to create the column related to the foreign key:

```
class CreateAreasTable extends Migration {

 /**
  * Run the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function up()
  {
    // Creates the cemeteries table
    Schema::create('areas', function($table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('region_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('region_id')->references('id')->on('regions');

        $table->string('name', 160)->unique();
        $table->timestamps();

    });
  }
}
```

Sometimes (depends on your database server) you'll have to create your foreign keys in two steps:

```
class CreateAreasTable extends Migration {

 /**
  * Run the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function up()
  {
    // Create the table and the foreign key column
    Schema::create('areas', function($table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('region_id')->unsigned();

        $table->string('name', 160)->unique();
        $table->timestamps();

    });

    // Create the relation
    Schema::tabe('areas', function($table)
    {
        $table->foreign('region_id')->references('id')->on('regions');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. So $table->foreign('columnname') ... doesn't create an integer based column if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: That's it. It just creates the relation between the tables.

Comment: That solves the error i was recieving, but has replaced it with another.

[Exception]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'nzf-org.#sql-107c_
c8' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table `areas` add constraint areas_region_id_f
oreign foreign key (`region_id`) references `regions` (`id`)) (Bindings: ar
ray (
))

Comment: That's a migration problem: $table->foreign() is run after the table is already created, so it is trying to create it again... I think you'll have to drop the table manually and run the migration again.

Comment: Migration's run order also matter here, so if you create a foreign key before the table, you will get error, In short, region table migration should run before areas migration.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I had to run the migrations in the order the depend on but still got the 1072 error. I expected the foreign() method creates the column. But thanks to you I got schooled :D

Answer (score 4):

and don't forget to make the foreign keys unsigned.

```
         $table->integer('region_id')->unsigned();
```

Comment: Why would I need to make my foreign keys unsigned? What does this do and what are the benefits?

Comment: It is a laravel doc advice: 

Note: When creating a foreign key that references an incrementing integer, remember to always make the foreign key column unsigned

Primary keys can not be negative so a foreign key pointing to them should also be an unsigned. This also allows doubles the number of keys you can have in that column.