# Laravel migrate creating table with more than one primary key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I issued the command:

```
php artisan generate:scaffold order --fields="customer_id:integer(11), order_date:date, notes:text”
```

When it gets to migrate, it ends with the error:

```
General error: 1 table "orders" has more than one primary key (SQL: create table "orders" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "customer_id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "order_date" date not null, "notes" text not null))
```

There is a Customer model and corresponding table that I am trying to reference with `customer_id` in the schema. However, it shouldn't be the primary key for the `orders` table.

Here is the `up()` code that is preventing migration from running:

```
    Schema::create('orders', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('customer_id', 11);
        $table->date('order_date');
        $table->text('notes');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: the generate:scaffold commands is generating the sql with 2 primary keys ( customer_id and id ) . Are you sure that's the up migrate that is not working ? Do you currently have a orders table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible problem might be :

[from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928740/foreign-keys-in-laravel-4-migrations-issue)

Root of problem is : column with foreign key must be same type as that key. And you have different types: INT/UNSIGNED INT

The documentation on Laravel [mentions this also](http://laravel.com/docs/schema#adding-indexes) :
Note: When creating a foreign key that references an incrementing integer, remember to always make the foreign key column unsigned.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you use the function `->integer()` with a second param. According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_integer) the second parameter expects a boolean to set autoincrement or not: `bool $autoIncrement = false`).

Try this:

```
Schema::create('orders', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('customer_id');
        $table->date('order_date');
        $table->text('notes');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: I think this should be the right answer, as it clearly was the issue here.