# laravel foreign key migration error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

Hi I'm trying to create a table which has foreign keys but when I use the `php artisan migrate` command I get the following error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                      
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint 
 (SQL: alter table 
`clients` add constraint clients_user_id_foreign foreign key (`user_id`) 
 references `users` (`id`))
```

My migration file is as so:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function($table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('user_id');
            $table->string('client_name');
            $table->string('client_code');
            $table->string('client_firstname');
            $table->string('client_surname');
            $table->string('client_email');
            $table->text('client_brief');
            $table->text('client_website');
            $table->timestamps('timecreated');
            $table->string('active');
        });

       Schema::table('clients', function($table) {
           $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
       });

    }
```

For my users table I am using Zizaco/Confide.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong any ideas?

Comment: One possibility... the data type for the two columns joined by a foreign key must be **exactly** the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user_id` should be an integer instead of string

```
Schema::create('clients', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); 
        $table->string('client_name');
        $table->string('client_code');
        $table->string('client_firstname');
        $table->string('client_surname');
        $table->string('client_email');
        $table->text('client_brief');
        $table->text('client_website');
        $table->timestamps('timecreated');
        $table->string('active');

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16934874
Be sure to use the "$table->unsignedInteger('user_id')" method instead of your "$table->string('user_id')".
The first one will create a int(10) column in your database, while the second one will result in a varchar(255) one, which doesn't match the foreign key constraints.